# String substitution for key value pairs in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to message some data of key values in arrays but stumped.

Here's what's in my array:

```
data = [ "name=abc", "title=analyst", "group=IT", "id=123"]
```

The mapping that I'm looking to translate:

```
mapping = { "name" => "EmployeeName", "title" => "JobTitle", "group" => "BusinessGroup", "id" => "EmployeeID"}
```

The expected result that I'm after:

```
data = [ "EmployeeName=abc", "JobTitle=analyst", "BusinessGroup=IT", "EmployeeID=123"]
```

Comment: Why the rush to select an answers? I expect several of us are still working on theirs.

Comment: I agree with @CarySwoveland you may receive various answers in different way. then select which is best match for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, and my apologies for the quickfire rush to select an answer. Truly appreciate the help and my apologies for being a noob in selecting the answer. Will let the queries brew a little in the future. Cheers all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `data` array and `mapping` hash, you can do the following using [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
  data.map do |i|
    key, value = i.split('=')
    "#{mapping[key]}=#{value}"
  end
# => ["EmployeeName=abc", "JobTitle=analyst", "BusinessGroup=IT", # "EmployeeID=123"]
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to `split` the same string twice, just to save a line of code?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to keep that in-line. But, definitely, I can use a block and  do it once and use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
data.map {|s| s.sub /\w+/, mapping }
# => ["EmployeeName=abc", "JobTitle=analyst", "BusinessGroup=IT", "EmployeeID=123"]
```

Comment: Lovely! No, sublime! The only hitch would be something like `'BusinessGroup=BusinessGroup'`, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you could use `/^\w+(?==)/` in that case or even `/^#{Regexp.union(mapping.keys)}(?==)/`

Comment: @Stefan, what was I thinking? It's `sub`, not `gsub`, so no problem.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland :)

Comment: @Santhosh thanks for the contribution mate, it's awesome. Just a quick question though, if I need to preserve say an additional key value that doesn't exist in the mapping array, how would I go about doing that? For example data = [ "name=abc", "type=permanent"] and result after mapping reads data = ["EmployeeName=abc","type=permanent"]. Thanks again!

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest the selected answer, with this change `"#{mapping[key] || key }=#{value}"`

Comment: Here's a one liner: `data.map {|s| k, v = s.split('='); "#{mapping[k] || k }=#{v}"}`

Comment: That's a "one-liner"? Hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.map { |str| str.split(/\s*=\s*/).tap { |k,_| k.replace(mapping[k]) }.join('=') }
  #=> ["EmployeeName=abc", "JobTitle=analyst", "BusinessGroup=IT",  "EmployeeID=123"]
```

I've split on `/\s*=\s*/`, rather than `"="`, in case there are any spaces before or after `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> data.map{|a| a.split("=")}.map{|e| mapping.has_key?(e[0]) ? "#{e[0] = mapping[e[0]]}=#{e[1]}" : "#{e[0]}\=#{e[1]}"}
 => ["EmployeeName=abc", "JobTitle=analyst", "BusinessGroup=IT", "EmployeeID=123"]
```